# How to insert file_path into database using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, file-upload

I am  having a problem with inserting file_path to database usingt Codeigniter, I have a form field where user can upload any jpg|png|gif file ,the uploaded file is successfully sent to a uploads directory and a success message is displayed. But how will I get the file_path of that particular file uploaded and insert it into database.

the code below works fine until I call the model:

```
`$this->upload_model->upload_path();`
```

so definately there is a problem with my model ,cant figure out.

This is my Controller:

```
class Upload extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
                $this->load->model('upload_model');
        }

        public function index()
        {
                $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
        }

        public function do_upload()
        {
                $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 100;
                $config['max_width']            = 1024;
                $config['max_height']           = 768;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
                {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
                }
                else
                {
                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                        // when the code below is uncommented it shows error,otherwise runs
                        // $this->upload_model->upload_path();

                        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);

                }
        }
}
```

This is my model(which shows error):

```
class Upload_model extends CI_Model {

// this function will be called instantenneously

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database();
    }
    public function upload_path(){

// ::::::::UNDER CONSTRUCTION::::::::::

        $data = array(
            'path' =>$upload_data['full_path'],

            );

        return $this->db->insert('upload', $data);


    }

}
```

the View:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php echo $error;?>

    <form method="POST" action="/sandeep/ci/index.php/upload/do_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" />

    <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

    <br /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array with whatever you need to upload in your db...and then insert it in the db put something like this under else

```
//create array to load to database
              $image_data = $this->upload->data();
                $insert_data = array(
                    'name' => $image_data['file_name'],
                    'path' => $image_data['full_path'],
                    'thumb_path'=> $image_data['file_path'] . 'thumbs/'. $image_data['file_name'],
                    'tag' => $tag
                     );

          $this->db->insert('photos', $insert_data);//load array to database
```

Comment: do i need to add in the last line :  ` return  $this->db->insert('photos', $insert_data);`

Comment: THANK YOU Parangan , the code works perfectly, I've been working all day to run this piece...thank you again